# How to configure Always ON High Availability on this infrastructure?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, high-availability

I have SQL 2017 Enterprise Edition

What would be the best way to set up High Availability in the below infrastructure?

Datacenter 1
WSFC and FCI: Node1, Node 2, Shared Storage

Datacenter 2
WSFC and FCI: Node3, Node 4, Shared Storage

Do I need to add Node3 to existing WSFC on Datacenter1? Then configure the rest
OR?
Do I need to add Node3 and Node4 to existing WSFC on  Datacenter1? Then configure the rest

Comment: I'm not sure that it's clear exactly what you're asking. Are you simply looking to convert your 2-node FCI to a 2-node Availability Group? Is there a disaster scenario or business objective that you're trying to cover where your existing FCI doesn't cover it?

Comment: I am just assuming here. If you have created 2 separate WSFC you might have to redo this. Reading [Stretch Cluster Replication Using Shared Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/stretch-cluster-replication-using-shared-storage) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reshape the configuration:

- place **node3** and **node4** in the *same WSFC* of the **node1** and **node2**.
- then *reinstall FCI* on **node3** and **node4**

At the end you have a FCI1 (node1+node2) in the *datacenter1*, and a FCI2 (node3+node4) in the *datacenter2*.

At this point you can configure an **Alwayson AG between FCI1 and FCI2**.

Comment: Thank you . So would that be called "Distributed AG"? If I am not mistaken